# Как отсортировать NSMutableArray?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Я хочу отсортировать массив в алфавитном порядке, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас массив из NSString*?

Тогда так:

```
NSMutableArray* array;
...
[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Сортирует по возрастанию.

Если же у вас кастомный тип, это будет немного сложнее, но тоже возможно.

Answer (score 4):

Для кастомных типов

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id ob2){
    //  сравниваем два объекта
    //  и возвращаем YES или NO
    return YES;
}];
```